# Send a ping to XMPP server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I'm using Openfire as the server for the XMPP. The problem I'm facing is that the user is being kicked out every few minutes although I changed the server settings to "not kick idle users".

I was searching about this problem, and I found from many posts that many people were facing the same problem and they solved it by sending constantly pings to the server.

And then I found the stanza for the ping in XMPP, which is the following:

```
<iq from='capulet.lit' to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' id='s2c1' type='get'>
  <ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
</iq>
```

But I'm not able to translate it to Javascript correctly.

I tried the following but it is still not working

```
setInterval(function(){
            var message = $msg({to: [server hostname] ,
                                    from: [user jid],
                                    "type": "get"})
                                     .c('query', {xmlns: "urn:xmpp:ping"});
                    connection.sendIQ(message);
},50000);
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using to create and send the stanzas exactly? PHP or Javascript? Or is it a combination of both? Also, you're building a message stanza but sending it as if it were an IQ stanza.

Comment: It's in javascript, I wrote php by mistake because I'm using it in other places. I have re-edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Strophe.js?

Comment: yes I'm using Strophe.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're building a message stanza instead of an IQ one. You need to create an IQ stanza to ping the server. The child element you created inside the stanza is also wrong. The element name should be `ping` instead of `query`.

```
connection.sendIQ($iq({to: server, from: jid, type: "get"}).c('ping', {xmlns: "urn:xmpp:ping"}));
```

Comment: Excellent, but it gives me bad request error as it is the 'get' method so i append the "/?<body rid='1'" with server name and now it works perfectly.